# Error en Netbeans java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/patrones

Tags: java, netbeans

Buenas estoy teniendo un problema con este programa que hice me da este error y he intentado de todo pero no funciona nada, estoy conectado a la base de datos pero no funciona . Aqui el codigo:

```
package conectaBD;
import java.sql.*;

public class NewClass {
public static void main(String args []){
       try{

      Connection MyConnection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/patrones","root","");


      Statement MyStatement= MyConnection.createStatement();


      ResultSet MyResultSet = MyStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM usuario2");


      while(MyResultSet.next()){
          System.out.println(MyResultSet.getString("id")+ " " 
          + MyResultSet.getString("nombre") + " ");
      }

      }catch(Exception e){

          System.out.println("NO CONECTA!!");
          e.printStackT**texto en negrita**race(); 
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya añadiste la librería de MySQL JDBC Driver?

Comment: Si era eso, muchas gracias Michell no habia hecho el tema de la Libreria :)